# setTimeout key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have the following code that moves through a sprite sheet with setTimeouts.
It works fine but I was wanted to know how to make it so that if I press the "m" key, it would just skip one frame at a time and stop (until m is pressed again), and once there are no more frames, the process should stop.

So if I press m, frame one passes, if I press m again then frame two passes and etc...until there are no more frames left.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {          
        if (e.keyCode == 77) {  
            setTimeout(function () {
                object.css('background-position', '-32px -0px');
            setTimeout(function () {
                object.css('background-position', '-64px -0px');
            setTimeout(function () {
                object.css('background-position', '-96px -0px');
            setTimeout(function () {
                object.css('background-position', '-128px -0px');
             }, 600);
             }, 600);
             }, 600);
             }, 600);
        }
});
```

I think getting rid of the setTimeouts might work, but would I just have to continually add if(e.keyCode...) ?

Hope I've been clear!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the position in a variable and decrement it (lower its value) on each keypress.

```js
    var pos = 0;
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {         
        if (e.keyCode == 77) { 
            pos -= 32;
            alert(pos);
            object.css('background-position', pos+'px -0px');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope I understood you correctly.